# JavaScript code to calculate percentage of entered number?

Tags: javascript

*Hi Everyone,*

*I am looking for a Javascript code which can calculate and split the percentage of entered number.*

**For Example:**
 if I entered "**100**" in textfield and when I click on button, it should show 60% of 100 (that means 60) and 40% of 100(that means 40).

If I entered **"50"** the answer should be **30 for 60%** and **20 for 40%.**

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: What is the logic behind the spliting

Comment: What you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You should have tried this yourself, anyways sharing you the basic code to achieve that

```
<input type="number" id="numberInput">
<button id="calculateBtn">Calculate</button>
<p id="outputDiv"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById('calculateBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const value = document.getElementById('numberInput').value;
    document.getElementById('outputDiv').textContent = `60% of ${value} is ${(value * 60) / 100} , 40% of ${value} is ${(value * 40) / 100}`;
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0x1bohgm/

Comment: Thank you so much Deepinder. I don't have my working copy with me. So I posted as plain text. Thank you so much for your help.